# 4-Bit Adder returns wrong results

Tags: verilog

```
module adder4(
output[3:0] sum,
output c_out,       // carry out
input[3:0] a, b,    // operands
input c_in);        // carry in

wire [2:0] c_o;
full_adder fa1(c_o[0],sum[0],a[0],b[0],c_in);
full_adder fa2(c_o[1],sum[1],a[1],b[1],c_o[0]);
full_adder fa3(c_o[2],sum[2],a[2],b[2],c_o[1]);
full_adder fa4(c_out,sum[3],a[3],b[3],c_o[2]);

endmodule

module full_adder(
    output sum,
    output c_out,   // carry out
    input a,
    input b,
    input c_in);    // carry in

wire sum1;
wire c_in1;
wire c_out2;
    half_adder ha1(sum1,c_in1,a,b);
    half_adder ha2(sum,c_out2,sum1,c_in);
    or(c_out,c_out2,c_in1);
endmodule


module half_adder(
    output sum,
    output c_out,   // carry out
    input a,
    input b);

assign sum=a^b;
assign c_out=a&&b;

endmodule
```

I tried to make a 4-bit adder from 4 full adders, but I keep getting the wrong results. The sum that I get when a=3 and b=8 is 9 instead of 11. I don't see the mistake. Can someone figure out what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your connections are wrong.  You are connecting `c_o[0]` to the `sum` port of `full_adder` (the same for `c_o[2:1]` and `c_out`).  Port order is important when instantiating by position.  The quickest fix is to use:

```
module full_adder(
    output c_out,   // carry out
    output sum,
```

It is generally a better practice to instantiate by name instead of position.  Obviously, this is more verbose, but it does help avoid your type of wiring bug:

```
full_adder fa1 (.c_out(c_o[0]) , .sum(sum[0]), .a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .c_in(c_in));
```

---

You could also take advantage of instance arrays:

```
full_adder fa[3:0] (
    .c_out  ({c_out, c_o}),
    .sum    (sum),
    .a      (a),
    .b      (b),
    .c_in   ({c_o, c_in})
);
```